# MongoDB Problems in Heroku

Tags: discord.js

I put this code in Heroku but for some reason is not working.

This is my code:

```
Client.on('ready', async () => {
  await connect(config.MongoPath, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log("Ready!") 
})
```

This is my schema:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const PendingList = Schema({
    id: String,
    PendingList: {
        default: [],
        type: Array
    }
});

module.exports = model('PendingList',PendingList);
```

I am receiving [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOMyI.png) in Heroku.

It works perfectly on my local machine but not Heroku.

Comment: Where is `connect` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your heroku app does not have the permissions to access your database cluster.

You need to go to your Mongo Atlas cluster [Log in here](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/register) and then whitelist heroku's IP inorder for the servers to access your DB

navigate to security > network access > and add this IP

[image]

Comment: That's not what the error is suggesting, therefore this answer does not help the OP to their problem.

Comment: @Tyler2P they said it worked in their local machine, which exactly means that their servers cant access the db :)

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @Tyler2P yep, i had this issue myself, + if connect is not defined it would throw a completely different error, moreover they're using async/await so its not an error with model loader

Comment: Thanks this fix my problem.

Comment: @Tyler2P there, and no problemo bud, happy to help